# Auto-import vue reactivity system in vitest for testing composables in Nuxt 3 and vitest

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vitest

I am using some utils in Nuxt 3. The vue reactivity system (`ref`, `computed`, ...) is also imported directly. However, it is not the case for the tests.

Running the spec file importing a `./useBusinessValidation` composable throws the error `ReferenceError: ref is not defined`

Source file `./useBusinessValidation`:

```js
import { MaybeRef } from "@vueuse/core"

export const useBusinessValidation = <T>(rule: (payload: T) => true | string, payload: MaybeRef<T>) => {
  const validation = computed(() => rule(unref(payload)))

  const isValid = computed(() => validation.value === true)
  const errorMessage = computed(() => isValid.value ? undefined : validation.value as string)

  return {
    isValid,
    errorMessage
  }
}
```

Spec file `useBusinessValidation.spec.ts`:

```js
import { useBusinessValidation } from "./useBusinessValidation"

describe('useBusinessValidation', async () => {
  it('should be valid with payload respecting the rule', () => {
    const rule = (x: number) => x > 0 ? true : `invalid ${x} number. Expected ${x} to be greater than 0.`
    const { isValid, errorMessage } = useBusinessValidation(rule, 0)

    expect(isValid.value).toBe(true)
    expect(errorMessage.value).toBe(undefined)
  });
})
```

and the `vitest.config.ts`

```js
{
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': '.',
      '~~': './',
      '@@': '.',
      '@@/': './',
      'assets': './assets',
      'public': './public',
      'public/': './public/'
    }
  },
  test: {
    globals: true,
    setupFiles: './test/setupUnit.ts',
    environment: 'jsdom',
    deps: { inline: [/@nuxt\/test-utils-edge/] },
    exclude: [
      'test/**/**.spec.ts',
      '**/node_modules/**',
      '**/dist/**',
      '**/cypress/**',
      '**/.{idea,git,cache,output,temp}/**'
    ]
  }
}
```

I also tried with the `@vitejs/plugin-vue` as

```js
plugins: [Vue()]
```

in the vitest config. It didn't work out.

Comment: Hi ! Did you find a solution for that ? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To auto-import in vitest, install the [unplugin-auto-import](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-auto-import).

Then, in the vitest.config.ts add:

```js
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite';

export default defineConfig({
...
  plugins: [
    AutoImport({
      imports: [
        'vue',
        // could add 'vue-router' or 'vitest', whatever else you need.
      ],
   }),
  ]
});
```

Comment: Altough this does work in the case of the original question to import `ref` from vue, I couldn't find a way yet to import nuxt3 specific functions like `useFetch` or `usePublicRuntimeConfig` that way yet.

Comment: @florian_ did you find a way yet to do this?

Comment: I did @AdamSilva! I'm using [nuxt-vitest](https://github.com/danielroe/nuxt-vitest) now. But beware, that it's in active development and likely not ready for every use-case.