# Vitest setup auto-import for Nuxt and pinia

Tags: nuxt.js, pinia, vitest

I'm trying to setup `vitest` + `@vue/test-utils` but I can't test some components that use `ref`(Vue) or `useCookie` (Nuxt), I have the same problem with Pinia as well where I import globally 2 functions in the nuxt.config.js like this

```
[
  '@pinia/nuxt',
  {
    autoImports: ['defineStore', 'acceptHMRUpdate'],
  }
]
```

This is my vitest.config.js setup:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue"
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    AutoImport({
      imports: ['vue'],
      dirs: ['./composables/']
    })
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    coverage: {
      provider: 'c8',
      reporter: 'html',
      reportsDirectory: './coverage'
    },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname, './')
    }
  },
})
```

and the component I'm trying to test is something like this:

```
<script setup>
import AButton from '~/components/atoms/a-button/a-button.vue'
...

defineProps({
  label: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
})

const show = ref(false)

const Squad = useCookie('squad', { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 })
const appStore = useAppStore()
```

In Nuxt 3 as you know you don't `import { ref } from vue` or `... useCookie from..` they are auto-imported but `vitest` doesn't recognize them, I saw a couple of questions but none have an answer that solves my problem.

These are some:

- [Auto-import vue reactivity system in vitest for testing composables in Nuxt 3 and vitest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72977834/auto-import-vue-reactivity-system-in-vitest-for-testing-composables-in-nuxt-3-an)
- [Testing Pinia store inside Nuxt3 with vitest throws `useRuntimeConfig` not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72192874/testing-pinia-store-inside-nuxt3-with-vitest-throws-useruntimeconfig-not-defin)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with refs and Nuxt 3 and I solved it by using unplugin-auto-import/vite

After installing, add the AutoImport configuration to the **vitest.config.ts**:

```
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import AutoImport from "unplugin-auto-import/vite";

export default {
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    AutoImport({
      imports: ["vue"],
    }),
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
  },
  coverage: {
    all: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: yes I managed to import vue stuff like you but I'm still unable to auto import Nuxt stuff

Comment: Hello, finally I found a solution for mocking the Nuxt auto imports in my test components. Here there's an example.  https://medium.com/@ana.robles.developer/nuxt-3-vitest-vue-test-utils-mockear-en-los-test-funciones-auto-importadas-2242297eb06d

Comment: mock everything doesn't really seem a robust solution, it solved it yes but not sure is the correct way. it would mean mock useRuntimeConfig or useCookie etc...

Comment: No final solution for this guys? The Ana hack doesn't work for me. Same error for useRoute, useHead, useSeoMeta.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [nuxt-vitest](https://github.com/danielroe/nuxt-vitest) plugin,

Install the following dependencies

`pnpm add -D nuxt-vitest vitest happy-dom vitest-environment-nuxt`

Add nuxt-vitest to your nuxt.config.js:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ...
  modules: [
    'nuxt-vitest'
  ]
})
```

Then create a vitest.config.js with the following content:

```
import { defineVitestConfig } from 'nuxt-vitest/config';
export default defineVitestConfig({
  test: {
    environment: 'nuxt',
  },
});
```

Please note this will return an error with `vitest` version 0.34 or above, **make sure to use `vitest` 0.33**

I reported the error on github https://github.com/danielroe/nuxt-vitest/issues/341

Comment: I'm not working on this project for the moment so I can't test it, though I did see it at the time and I see that is still there the warning, it says WARNING: This library is in active development and you should pin the patch version before using. Doesn't feel like something you'd like to use in prod.

Comment: Still better approach than manually adding every nuxt composable that's auto-imported, also if it gets installed on the devDepencies it wouldn't even make it to production, this is just for  unit testing, which you can have pipelines run before doing a build

Comment: sure this would go in the CI/CD and not in prod but still unstable dependencies compared with other ones :)